# Error 0x80004005 when reading dump file with WinDbg

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I'm working on a 32 bit application which sometimes causes a certain 64 bit Windows 7 machine to crash. I've generated a dump file of the crash using the ProcDump utility from Sysinternals. (I used the command "procdump -ma -h MyApplication.exe".) Now, when I open the dump file with WinDbg, I get this error:

"Failure when opening dump file 'MyDumpFile.dmp', HRESULT 0x80004005. It may be corrupt or in a format not understood by the debugger."

This happens both when running WinDbg X86 on a 32 bit Windows XP machine, and when running WinDbg AMD64 on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine. Can you explain this?

EDIT - additional info: When running dumpchk on the file, it says:

"Minidump does not have system info. Could not open dump file [MyDumpFile.dmp], HRESULT 0x80004005 'Unspecified error'".

Maybe the dump file is simply corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you does not use procdump correctly.

Can you try to use ADPlus (which is also in Debugging Tools for Windows) to capture crash dumps?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350